# Declaração de objeto em Javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

```
function List(){
   this.listSize = 0;
   this.pos = 0;
   this.dataStore = []; 
};
```

Posso considerar esse trecho de código como a criação de um objeto List?

Comment: Aqui também podes marcar como aceite a resposta que achares que melhor respondeu à tua pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript é uma linguagem multi-paradigma. Entre os paradigmas suportadas, está a Orientação a Objetos.

Você pode criar objetos de várias formas. Nesta forma, eu crio um objeto list, com as propriedades listSize, pos e dataStore, e um método chamado myMethod(). Não é uma definição de uma "classe" (definindo classe como um modelo de objeto), mas apenas um objeto. Nesta forma, cada instância de List terá uma cópia da função myMethod().

```
function List() {
    this.listSize = 0;
    this.pos = 0;
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.myMethod = function () {
        alert('Este é um método');
    };
}

var list = new List();
```

A forma que eu utilizo para definir uma classe é através de prototypes, onde você cria um "protótipo" de uma função, e posteriormente cria objetos que são instâncias deste protótipo.

```
List = function () {
    this.dataStore = [];
};

List.prototype.listSize = 0;

List.prototype.pos = 0;

List.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    alert('Este é um método');
};

var list = new List();
```

Utilizando esta forma você irá consumir menos memória, pois a definição de myMethod() (e demais variáveis) é compartilhada entre todos os objetos que usam este protótipo de objeto. Além disto, editores que possuem auto-complete vão identificar que o seu objeto possui esta função/propriedade :-).

UPDATE: Corrigido conforme a observação de @bfavaretto e desta página [Optimizing JavaScript Code](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript).

Comment: Por que você colocou as propriedades no protótipo? O método, ok, vai lá mesmo. Mas as propriedades precisam ser por instância. Do jeito como você fez, fica mais confuso, e pode causar efeitos indesejados.

Comment: As propriedades estão no protótipo para reduzir o uso de memória. O objeto utilizará o valor padrão do protótipo até o momento em que receber um valor próprio, conforme o exemplo abaixo (assumindo que  List é definido no formato de prototype). https://jsfiddle.net/lucasdamiani/m3svaq8b/

Quais efeitos indesejados que podem ocorrer por usar a declaração no prototype?

Comment: O efeito indesejado é manipular propriedades de uma propriedade que seja um objeto e esteja no protótipo. Por exemplo, no seu último bloco de código, `list.dataStore.push(1,2,3)` popularia a própria array que está no protótipo.

Comment: Realmente isto se aplica a objetos atribuídos por referência, e não por valor. Portanto a sua observação é válida. Não li este link corretamente da primeira vez. [Optimizing JavaScript code](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript), aqui diz claramente que a forma que sugeri é adequada, mas não deve ser usada para tipos atribuídos por referência.

Comment: Legal Lucas. Eu comentei essas coisas mais porque acredito que os iniciantes pudessem se confundir, especialmente os que conhecem o paradigma tradicional de OOP, baseado em classes e não protótipos. Colocar um objeto dentro do protótipo pode até ser útil, mas quem usa precisa saber o que está fazendo.

Answer (score 8):

Não. Isso é uma função. Poderia ser chamada informalmente de "classe `List`", se a intenção for usá-la como função construtora, com o operador `new`. Nesse uso, aí sim você estará criando um objeto do tipo `List` (ou "uma instância de `List`"):

```
function List(){
   this.listSize = 0;
   this.pos = 0;
   this.dataStore = []; 
};
var objetoLista = new List();
```