# Padrões de classe

Tags: javascript, design-pattern

Não estou conseguindo literatura em português, então achei [um artigo em inglês](http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/javascript-class-pattern.html) que não entendi bem o conceito, alguém poderia me ajudar me explicando as diferenças:

1. Escrever uma Classe com os métodos dentro da Classe:

   ```
   function MyClass() {
       this.greet = function() {
           console.log('Hello!');
       };
   }
   var inst = new MyClass();
   inst.greet(); // => 'Hello!'
   ```
2. Escrever uma Classe com os métodos fora da Classe:

   ```
   //Classe aqui
   function MyClass() {}

   //metodo usando prototype ( escrito fora da Classe )
   MyClass.prototype.greet = function() {
       console.log('Hello!');
   };
   var inst = new MyClass();
   inst.greet(); // => 'Hello!'
   ```

Aparentemente ficaria a mesma coisa, mas o autor desses exemplos diz que o 1º código é ineficiente, então gostaria que alguém me explicasse se isso é verdade e o por que, tanto para verdade ou falsa afirmação do autor

Comment: Eu posso dizer que, se você quiser criar uma variável privada dentro de MyClass, você não conseguirá acessá-la se fizer com `prototype`. Nesse caso, a solução seria declará-la com `this` mesmo.

Comment: Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65131 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o primeiro caso, você terá uma função `greet` para cada variável instanciada. Por exemplo, se você instanciar duas variáveis `MyClass`, cada uma terá sua `greet`.
Já com o segundo caso, todas as instâncias compartilham o mesmo código dessa função, então você só terá a instância `greet` de `MyClass` e não de cada variável.